# Mac Automator. Automatic processing of 4000 files

Tags: macos, automator

I would like to ask you if you know and can give a clue whether it is possible to perform such tasks with the help of the Automator app on Mac:

1. Run application (blender)
2. Import the 3D model
   and then in the loop:
3. Assign a texture (one of the 4000 in the folder)
4. Export the file (3d model with the name of texture)
5. Assign another texture from the folder
6. Export a file (3d model with the name of texture)
   and so on... to process all the textures in the folder

Many thanks!

I searched for a solution, but unfortunately, none of them gave an answer to my problem. Especially when it comes to working with multiple different files.

Comment: Is blender even scriptable?

Comment: Blender is not scriptable via automator, but it _is_ [scriptable through Python](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_quickstart.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link @Alladinian. So I have to try learn python :) But to be sure before I start. Thanks to python I will be able to get what i need? (replace texture, export, replace texture, export etc...)? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Eisenheim It's difficult to say, since I've barely used the API but my understanding is that the majority of functionality is exposed. You could reach out to the [blender dev forums](https://devtalk.blender.org/c/other-topics/python/6) and maybe people with experience in the subject could guide you.